# How do i handle if the input is a string and requiremnt is an integer

Tags: python

```
Error: Error: if n == 0 or n>4: 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment.
```

Tried isdigit method, but seems not working. what is the issue ?

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys
class Person:

    def __init__(self, firstname=None, lastname=None, age=None, gender=None):
        self.fname = firstname
        self.lname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender



    def display(self):
        found = False

        n1 = raw_input("Enter for Search Criteria\n1.FirstName ==  2.LastName ==     3.Age == 4.Gender : " )

        print "Not a valid input"
        if n1.isdigit():
            n = int(n1)
        else:
            print "Enter Integer only" 

        if n == 0 or n>4:
            print "Enter valid search "

        if n == 1:
            StringSearch = raw_input("Enter FirstName :")
            for records in list_of_records:
                if StringSearch in records.fname:
                    found = True
                    print records.fname, records.lname, records.age, records.gender

            if not found:
                print "No matched record"

        if n == 2:
            StringSearch = raw_input("Enter LastName :")
            for records in list_of_records:
                if StringSearch in records.lname:
                    found = True
                    print records.fname, records.lname, records.age, records.gender

            if not found:
                print "No matched record"

        if n == 3:
            StringSearch = raw_input("Enter Age :")
            for records in list_of_records:
                if StringSearch in records.age:


        if not found:
            print "No matched record"

        if n == 4:
            StringSearch = raw_input("Enter Gender(M/F) :")
            for records in list_of_records:
                if StringSearch in records.gender:
                    found = True
                    print records.fname, records.lname, records.age, records.gender

            if not found:
            print "No matched record"



f= open("abc","r")
list_of_records = [Person(*line.split()) for line in f]
#for record in list_of_records:


for per in list_of_records:
    per.display()
```

PLease help me out in how to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = 0
if n1.isdigit():
    n = int(n1)
else:
    """If the execution comes here (not n1.isdigit())
    the variable `n` will remain undefined.
    Therefore you should define it in this block or before if,
    say initially setting it to zero.

    """

    print "Enter Integer only"
```

http://codepad.org/5PNWnDrN

Another approach:

```
try:
    n = int(n1)
except ValueError, TypeError:
    n = 0
```

http://codepad.org/JEdXO9dz

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

Comment: It could not raise that if you did what I said.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, you are doing a few things wrong.

First of all, `raw_input` will always give you a string.

So you need to convert it into an integer anyway. But also, you are using the variable `n` in parts of your code that it might not exist at yet.

You need to change this part:

```
    print "Not a valid input"
    if n1.isdigit():
        n = int(n1)
    else:
        print "Enter Integer only"
```

To this:

```
    try:
        n = int(n1)
    except:
        print "Enter Integer only" 
        raise
```

Unless you want to keep asking until valid input is received, then make a function:

```
def get_user_int(prompt="Enter an integer: "):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(prompt)))
        except:
            print 'Try again'
```

And call it like this:

```
n = get_user_int("Enter choice for Search Criteria\n - 1.FirstName\n - 2.LastName\n - 3.Age\n - 4.Gender\n> ")
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment...still the same problem .....my input is Enter for Search Through
1.FirstName :  2.LastName :  3.Age : 4.Gender: 5.Exit== dfs

Comment: I am not going to babysit you on this code and do all your work. You most assuredly did something incorrect, but if you use my solution correctly you should be fine. Try again.

Answer (score -1):

Your're testing for n == something condition before setting the value of n. Simply initialize it to zero or whatever else default value.

```
def display(self):
        found = False
        n = 0
```

Comment: it does not address the actual problem

Comment: @lejlot Actually it *solves* the actual problem. But it does not provide a solution for the OP to improve their code. Nor does it answer the OP's question about what is wrong. But if this answer was used, there would be no visible problem.... But it is indeed not a real solution.

Comment: Are you both saying that his isdigit is not working? Because the actual problem with the code is uninitialized n.

Comment: @inbas it solves the error, not the problem. Although these are just linguistic aspects. The main question was "how do I handle" not "why is this error appearing" - and this question only answer this small subproblem. So (to address kgu's comment) the **actual** problem is not uninitialized n, but wrong approach to the conversion problem. Lack of initialization is just a minor bug, unrelevant to the whole issue.